# Set MultiLevel TickLabels For Excel Chart with EPPlus, not using Interop

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

The same can be done on vba:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.MultiLevel = True
```

How to change a property using Epplus? So far only found how to change TickLabelPosition:

```
excelChart.XAxis.TickLabelPosition = eTickLabelPosition.Low;
```

Comment: Latest [docs](https://www.epplussoftware.com/docs/5.5/api/OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.html) suggest this is not implemented

Comment: @stuartd, thanks for answer. I couldn't find anything either.